# Get combined intervals for registrations and statuses

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, gaps-and-islands

I want to calculate agent statuses (ready, break, lunch, training) adjusted for registration.

PostgreSQL version is 11 (possible upgrade to 13).

Table with registrations:

| dt_start | dt_end | agent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 08:00:00 | 2024-01-01 08:10:00 | 3148 |
| 2024-01-01 08:20:00 | 2024-01-01 08:30:00 | 3148 |
| 2024-01-01 08:31:00 | 2024-01-01 08:33:00 | 3148 |
| 2024-01-01 08:35:00 | 2024-01-01 08:38:00 | 3148 |
| 2024-01-01 08:40:00 | 2024-01-01 08:41:00 | 3148 |
| 2024-01-01 08:44:00 | null | 3148 |
| 2024-01-01 08:25:00 | 2024-01-01 08:35:00 | 31 |
| 2024-01-01 08:40:00 | 2024-01-01 08:45:00 | 31 |

Table with agent_statuses

| dt | agent_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 08:00:00 | 3148 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 08:15:10 | 3148 | 2 |
| 2024-01-01 08:22:30 | 3148 | 3 |
| 2024-01-01 08:34:00 | 3148 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 08:41:00 | 3148 | 2 |
| 2024-01-01 08:45:00 | 3148 | 3 |
| 2024-01-01 08:20:00 | 31 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 08:35:00 | 31 | 2 |

https://dbfiddle.uk/R5bvCJtp

I would like to get this result:

*D - for description, not for result.

| *D | dt_start | dt_end | agent_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 08:00:00 | 2024-01-01 08:10:00 | 3148 | 1 |
| 2 | 2024-01-01 08:20:00 | 2024-01-01 08:22:30 | 3148 | 2 |
| 3 | 2024-01-01 08:22:30 | 2024-01-01 08:30:00 | 3148 | 3 |
| 4 | 2024-01-01 08:31:00 | 2024-01-01 08:33:00 | 3148 | 3 |
| 5 | 2024-01-01 08:35:00 | 2024-01-01 08:38:00 | 3148 | 1 |
| 6 | 2024-01-01 08:40:00 | 2024-01-01 08:41:00 | 3148 | 1 |
| 7 | 2024-01-01 08:44:00 | 2024-01-01 08:45:00 | 3148 | 2 |
| 8 | 2024-01-01 08:45:00 | null | 3148 | 3 |
| 9 | 2024-01-01 08:25:00 | 2024-01-01 08:35:00 | 31 | 1 |
| 10 | 2024-01-01 08:40:00 | 2024-01-01 08:45:00 | 31 | 2 |

Description

1. User 3148. Set status 1 at 08:00:00. Registered at 08:00:00. Next status set at 08:15:10, but user have register until 08:10:00. Result start 08:00:00, end 08:10:00.
2. User 3148. Set status 2 at 08:15:10, but registered at 08:20:00.  Next status set at 08:22:30. User steel registered. Result start 08:20:00, end 08:22:30
3. User 3148. Set status 3 at 08:22:30, user registered. Next status set at 08:34:00, but user registered until 08:30:00. Result Start 08:22:30, end 08:30:00.
4. User 3148. Status without change. Have one more registration between 08:22:30 and 08:34:00. Register from 08:31:00 to 08:33:00. Result start 08:31:00, end 08:33:00
5. User 3148. Set status 1 at 08:34:00, but registration from 08:35:00. Next status set at 08:41:00, but registration until 08:38:00. Result start 08:35:00, end 08:38:00.
6. User 3148. Status without change. Have one more registration between 08:34:00 and 08:41:00. Register from 08:40:00 to 08:41:00. Result start 08:40:00, end 08:41:00
7. User 3148. Set status 2 at 08:41:00, but registered at 08:44:00.  Next status set at 08:45:00. User steel registered. Result start 08:44:00, end 08:45:30
8. User 3148. Set status 3 at 08:45:00, steel registered. 3 is current status.
9. User 31. Set status 1 at 08:20:00. Registered at 08:25:00. Next status set at 08:35:00, user registered until 08:35:00. Result start 08:25:00, end 08:35:00.
10. User 31. Set status 2 at 08:35:00. Registered at 08:40:00. Status no change, but user registered until 08:45:00. Result start 08:40:00, end 08:45:00.

The logic is this:

- If there is a registration, it overlaps the agent status, correct it as is.
- If there was no registration at all during the period, no status record is added.
- If necessary, we adjust the beginning or end of processing of registration data.

Comment: The last 4 result rows don't seem to follow the same logic as the ones before. Can you check again, maybe fix, and certainly explain the results. Also, please *always* declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for your comment. You were right about the mistake. Made corrections.

Comment: Preliminary result on PLSQL https://dbfiddle.uk/deoP7o50